# Read (m x n) comma separated lines of a .txt file

Tags: matlab, file-io

Hello I have these kind of data in a text file and i wanted to read the data inside it.

```
2003,04,15,15,15,00,38.4279,-76.61,1565,3.7,0.0,38.19,-999,-999,3.9455,3.1457,2.9253

2003,04,15,16,50,00,38.368,-76.5,1566,3.7,0.0,35.01,-999

2003,04,15,17,50,00,38.3074,-76.44
```

I have used the following codes:

```
a= zeros(4460,216);
nl = a(:,1);
nc = a(1,:); 

if fid>0
  for i = 1:length(nl)
    d = textscan(Ligne,'%f','whitespace',',');
    numbers = d{:}';    
    D = a(i) + numbers;
    i = i+1;
  end
  Ligne = fgetl(fid);
end
```

The problem is that i cant implement the matrix D. The data are being replaced each time. Can somebody help me please?

Comment: Could you kindly accept an answer or update your question in case you still got problems?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming your file looks like:

```
Header
Header
Header

2003,04,15,15,15,00,38.4279,-76.61,1565,3.7,0.0,38.19,-999,-999,3.9455,3.1457,2.9253

2003,04,15,16,50,00,38.368,-76.5,1566,3.7,0.0,35.01,-999

2003,04,15,17,50,00,38.3074,-76.44
```

In the example you have **4** headerlines and the delimiter is **`','`**. Now just use [**`importdata`**](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/importdata.html) as a very convenient import function:

```
X = importdata('myData.txt',',',4)
```

---

which returns:

```
X = 

          data: [3x17 double]
      textdata: {4x17 cell}
    colheaders: {1x17 cell}
```

`X.data` contains your numeric data. As the data in your file has a different number of entries in every row, **missing values are filled with `NaN`**. `X.textdata` contains the skipped header lines as strings.

You can process them, if needed with textscan:

```
additionalInformation = textscan(X.textdata, ... )
```

The alternative [**suggested by Shai**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29341290/2605073) using [**`csvread`**](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/csvread.html) with the row offset set to **4** does the job as well. But be aware that **missing values are replaced with zeros**, what I personally dislike for further processing of data. Especially as your actual data also contains zeros.

```
X = csvread('myData.txt',4)
```

Comment: hello, sorry for late reply. Importdata also works just fine. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered using [`csvread`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/csvread.html)?

```
D = csvread( filename );
```

---

Regarding your code, you have two major bugs

1. `D = a(i)+numbers;` - you actually override `D` at each iteration. Try `D(i,:) = a(i,:)+numbers;` instead
2. `i=i+1;` - you change the loop variable inside the loop! if you are using a `for`-loop on `i` you do not need to increment it manually.

And some comments:

1. It is best [not to use `i` as a variable name in Matlab](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14790740/1714410).
2. You pre-allocated `a` but not `D`, consider pre-allocating `D` as well.

Comment: Yeah the problem is that i have got few data in string format at the top of the file, thats why im reading line by line. If i use .csv i need to delete the data on top.

Comment: @Sevian Have a closer look at the doc. You can skip the header of your file by defining a row offset.

Answer (score 0):

You already said it: D is replaced every time. This is happening since you don't specify indices when accessing D. You should do something like

```
D = zeros(size(a))
....
if ...
  for ... 
    ...
    D(i) = a(i) + numbers;
    ...
  end
end
```

But as Shai pointed out, there might be a simpler solution to your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Finally i have used these code lines. 
        D = NaN(size(a));
        i=1;

```
while ~(Ligne==-1)

    d = textscan(Ligne,'%f','whitespace',',');
    numbers = d{:}';    
    D(i,:) = numbers;
    Ligne = fgetl(fid);
    i=i+1;

end
```

Comment: But for what reason? This code is so slow compared to other answers provided.

Comment: I have approximately 100 unwanted rows of other data before the data i wanted to extract from the .txt file. So i needed an automated code to read all file having this kind of format. I had to read line by line to extract the relevant information needed. I will surely keep your codes it might help in the futur. Thank you so much.

Comment: I understand. But then you should still use `X = importdata( ... )` and then just use textscan for your header with `... = textscan(X.textdata, ...)`. Have a look at my edited answer to see what I mean. It is really not very fast to read all your data line by line, if you could load it at once.